# in jQuery, prevent deselecting all other options in a multiple select with "on"

Tags: jquery, html

I have a multiple select with options added after the page loads. I want the user to be able to click an option to select/deselect by clicking the option, without having to press the control button, and without it clearing all previously selected options. I have this working with a select that is initially loaded in the HTML, but not a select that contains options added through jQuery.

```
$(document).on("mousedown","#mySelect option",function(){                  
  if ($(this).prop("selected"))
  {
         $(this).prop("selected",false);
  }       
  else
  {
         $(this).prop("selected", true);
  } 
});




<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
    <!-- These options are added after the page loads -->
    <option id="id0" value="v0">T0</option>
    <option id="id1" value="v1">T1</option>
    <option id="id2" value="v2">T2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'd suggest not using a select input for this, click events on options are going to vary from browser to browser.

Comment: try not to use `on` on `document` whenever possible.

Comment: @Jashwant It was my understanding that using document.on was necessary for elements that are added after the page loads. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: It would be better to use an element above the dynamic element that doesn't get removed. The closer to the element the better.

Comment: In your case, you could have added to `#mySelect` as it was already present and only options were dynamically added.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I changed my code to an element rather than using document. I'll look into using something besides a select, as you mentioned, this is working in Chrome, but not IE or Firefox.